# $S_n=Z_n$? Arithmetic progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions

$S_n$ is the sum of the first "n" numbers of the arithmetic progression "9,16,23...";

$Z_n$ is the sum of the first "n" numbers of the arithmetic progression "4035,4038,4041..."

For what values (not 0) do you have "$S_n=Z_n$"?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you write down a closed formula for $S_n$ and $Z_n$? Set them equal -- you get a quadratic equation in $n$. Solve.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$ term of an arithmetic progression $(a_n)_{n\ge0}$ with ratio $r$ is
$$a_n=a_0+n r$$ so the sum is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k=(n+1)a_0+r\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
hence in our case we look for $n$ such that
$$9(n+1)+7\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=4035(n+1)+3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\iff n=\frac{4028\times2}{4}=2014$$

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand many things!

Comment: You're welcome.